# Cross join two dataframes by key column using condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have two dataframes.

```
mydata1=structure(list(ID_WORKES = c(58005854L, 58005854L, 58002666L, 
58002666L), ID_SP_NAR = c(463L, 1951L, 21L, 465L), KOD_DEPO = c(3786L, 
3786L, 1439L, 1439L), KOD_DOR = c(58L, 58L, 92L, 92L), COLUMN_MASH = c(6L, 
6L, 5L, 5L), prop_violations = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0.2", 
"1"), class = "factor"), mash_score = c(0L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("ID_WORKES", 
"ID_SP_NAR", "KOD_DEPO", "KOD_DOR", "COLUMN_MASH", "prop_violations", 
"mash_score"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

mydata2=structure(list(ID_SP_NAR = c(463L, 1951L, 21L, 465L, 500L, 600L
)), .Names = "ID_SP_NAR", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

i need crossjoin merge these dataframes by `ID_SP_NAR`. Mydata2 contatins only key variable ID_SP_NAR.

I need join this in such a way that if the `id_workers` does not have any codes from the ID_SP_NAR from mydata2, then these code are inserted into the dataset, but for them in variables `prop_violations` and `mash_score` must be inserted zero values.

I.E. `SP_ID_NAR` in mydata2 has such values

```
ID_SP_NAR
463
1951
21
465
500
600
```

`ID_workes =58005854` has
463,
1951
but another not have.
and 
`ID_workes =58002666` has  21 and 465 and not anonter!

So desired output after cross join

```
   ID_WORKES ID_SP_NAR KOD_DEPO KOD_DOR COLUMN_MASH prop_violations mash_score
1   58005854       463     3786      58           6             0.2          0
2   58005854      1951     3786      58           6               1          2
3   58005854        21     3786      58           6               0          0
4   58005854       465     3786      58           6               0          0
5   58005854       500     3786      58           6               0          0
6   58005854       600     3786      58           6               0          0
7   58002666        21     1439      92           5               1          2
8   58002666       465     1439      92           5               1          2
9   58002666       500     1439      92           5               0          0
10  58002666       600     1439      92           5               0          0
11  58002666       463     1439      92           5               0          0
12  58002666      1951     1439      92           5               0          0
```

KOD_DEPO,KOD_DOR,COLUMN_MASH have fixed value , it must be saved too.

How to do that?
`merge(mydata1,mydata2, by = ID_SP_NAR)` is not working( i try use via left join doesn't work), it doesn't insert zeros as i want .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `complete` from `tidyr` to expand the dataset based on the 'ID_WORKES' and the valuse of 'ID_SP_NAR' in the second dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata1 %>% 
   mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
   complete(ID_WORKES, ID_SP_NAR = mydata2$ID_SP_NAR,
            fill = list(prop_violations = '0', mash_score = 0)) %>%
     fill(3:5)
# A tibble: 12 x 7
#   ID_WORKES ID_SP_NAR KOD_DEPO KOD_DOR COLUMN_MASH prop_violations mash_score
#       <int>     <int>    <int>   <int>       <int> <chr>                <dbl>
# 1  58002666        21     1439      92           5 1                        2
# 2  58002666       463     1439      92           5 0                        0
# 3  58002666       465     1439      92           5 1                        2
# 4  58002666       500     1439      92           5 0                        0
# 5  58002666       600     1439      92           5 0                        0
# 6  58002666      1951     1439      92           5 0                        0
# 7  58005854        21     1439      92           5 0                        0
# 8  58005854       463     3786      58           6 0.2                      0
# 9  58005854       465     3786      58           6 0                        0
#10  58005854       500     3786      58           6 0                        0
#11  58005854       600     3786      58           6 0                        0
#12  58005854      1951     3786      58           6 1                        2
```

Comment: very good solution, but can you answer me, why if i run this code on my server in R it is good works , but when i run it on my home PC i get error  Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: `as_dictionary()` is defunct as of rlang 0.3.0.
Please use `as_data_pronoun()` instead. My server and my home pc have same OS win 7 x32 .What difference, maybe i have different version of tidyverse?

Comment: @G-spot  Looks like your versions may not be uptodate for packages.  What is your R version and dplyr/rlang/tidyr versions.  I used `R 3.6.0` with `dplyr_0.8.3`, `rlang_0.4.0`, `tidyr_‘0.8.3.9000’`